# JPQL find entity by exact array match

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have entity `Monitor` that contains attribute `categories` which is Set of entity `Category`. Is it possible to use JPQL to find entity `Monitor` by Set of `Categories`? 
Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT m from Monitor m where m.categories = :cats")
Monitor findByCategories(@Param("cats") Set<MessageCategory> cats);
```

This snippet throws an error `com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: syntax error at or near "."`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be the SQL query in this case?

Comment: Actually after rereading, it's not a duplicate, sorry.

Comment: invalid JPQL. You can't do "Set = Set". Consult a basic JPQL doc or the JPA spec. JPQL has "IN (...)" or "MEMBER OF"

Comment: Thought about a solution for you. You can pass the size of your set as a parameter,  select all the monitors with that size using `SIZE(m.categories) = :numCats` (also change the method to return a list). And then in code iterate over the list and check if they have the same categories with `Set.containsAll()` (Also make sure it's not the same monitor).

Comment: Thx @Oleg, i did it as you suggested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Monitor has only one categorie, so you can use IN clause in the query:

```
@Query("SELECT m from Monitor m where m.categories IN :cats")
```

But if your Monitor.categories field is a list this won't be working. There should be more complicated logic.

Updated 11.08.2017:
As I wrote in comments, you can transform list of category ids into the one string and compare with another. For this case the best way is create a view, but unfortunately this decision depends on SQL-engine. For PostgreSQL you can use something like this:

```
select m.*, string_agg(mc.catid, ',') as catids 
FROM monitor as m
LEFT JOIN messagecategories as mc on mc.monitor_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Comment: Monitor has set of categories, so i need to find another monitor that has exactly same set of categories :( So you saying that it is not possible?

Comment: There is nothing impossible! ))
You can transform these categories into the one string (ordered of course) and compare them. It will be the easiest way. I would create a view for this.